# Question about C++

Tags: c++, arrays, serial-communication

This is perhaps quite a simple one for some of you.

I was looking at the following serial read function and I can't quite comprehend what `&prefix[2]` does here. Does it mean only two bytes can be filled or something else ?

I should also mention this is part of the player/stage platform.

```
while (1)
{
  cnt = 0;
  while (cnt != 1)
  {
    if ((cnt += read(fd, &prefix[2], 1)) < 0)
    {
      perror("Error reading packet header from robot connection: P2OSPacket():Receive():read():");
      return (1);
    }
  }

  if (prefix[0] == 0xFA && prefix[1] == 0xFB)
  {
    break;
  }

  GlobalTime->GetTimeDouble(&timestamp);

  prefix[0] = prefix[1];
  prefix[1] = prefix[2];

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fragment implements a shift register of the size 3.

The oldest value is in `prefix[0]` and the latest in `prefix[2]`. That's why the address of `prefix[2]` is passed to the function `read()`.

The loop is left, when the previous two bytes have been `FA FB`, the current (last received) byte is in `prefix[2]`. The function is left before that point, if nothing could be read (the return value of `read` differs from 1).

This shift register is used when you can't predict if other bytes are received in front of the *sync characters* `FA FB`. Reading three bytes with each read operation would not allow to synchronize somewhere in a data stream.

Comment: thanks man. you saved my hours of head scratching over a simple thing. i was looking at the big picture of reading the bytes and kind of lost the plot.

Comment: bdw any reason why its done this way rather than reading the header or the first 3 bytes in a single loop ?

Comment: You want to check for the sync bytes against each position in the stream. When reading 3 bytes a lot of problems occure. You will need a state machine to survive. Moving the bytes around is much cheaper.

Answer (score 3):

The call `read(fd, &prefix[2], 1)` just means "store a single byte in `prefix[2]`".

In general, `&a[n]` is the same address as `(&a) + n`

Comment: thats what my guess was too. but can you understand what the rest of the code does ? This is suppose to be a simple while loop to read the first two bytes from a com port.

Comment: it's some sort of framing detection - it's looping until seeing `0xfa 0xfb nn`

Answer (score 2):

It is reading into an array called prefix, starting at an offset two places from the start of the array. In this case, only a single character is being read, but one could read more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this piece of code is reading a serial communications stream waiting for the start of a header which is marked with `FA`, `FB`.  The `while` loop reads characters singly into `prefix[2]` and shuffles them backwards through the array.

I think that the use of `&prefix[2]` is a trick which enables the next character in the header to appear in the `prefix` array when the `while` loop quits through the `break`.